# Problems with .htaccess and WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

Ok so i've tried finding the solution to this issue for many hours now. Basically i've got a script called view_app.php which takes a get variable of a. I was wanting to make it prettier by using .htaccess to make the url mydomain.com/a/VARIABLE but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Site/
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)/$ /Site/view_app.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have also gone into the httpd.conf and set AllowOveride to All but I am still getting the issue of it not rewriting and just throwing a 404 error. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Site/
RewriteRule a/(.*)/$ view_app.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried this and still it did not work, still throwing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

When using RewriteRule, you should not include the base or domain name in the line. Also, make sure you turn on the RewriteEngine. Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Site/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2
```

it will rewrite to domain/a/1

Comment: In my post I did show that I had turned on the RewriteEngine, but still this did not work, its still throwing a 404 error

Comment: please add the following .htaccess file which should be in the site folder      RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?$1=$2